# Compose CameraX takePicture() does not return on sdk 29

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I use cameraX in compose with the following code to show a preview and to take images. I now encountered multiple reports from users on SDK level 29 that they cant take pictures. After debugging with an emulator on SDK level 29, takePicture () seems to never return on that sdk level.

So far I found no obvious error in my code and nothing useful when googling that problem. Does anybody encountered the same or has an idea?

```
 val localContext = LocalContext.current
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    val cameraProviderFuture = remember {
        ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(localContext)
    }

    val cam = remember { mutableStateOf<Camera?>(null) }
    val imageCapture = remember { mutableStateOf<ImageCapture?>(null) }

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                val previewView = PreviewView(context)
                val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
                val selector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                    .build()
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

                imageCapture.value = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

                cam.value = cameraProviderFuture.get().bindToLifecycle(
                    lifecycleOwner,
                    selector,
                    preview,
                    imageCapture.value
                )

                previewView
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )

        DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
            onDispose {
                cameraProviderFuture.get().unbindAll()
            }
        }

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = targetFile) {
            targetFile?.let {
                val outputFileOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
                    .Builder(targetFile)
                    .build()
                imageCapture.value?.takePicture(   <---- Does not return on SDK 29
                    outputFileOptions,
                    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                    object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                        override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                            onPictureTakenClicked()
                        }

                        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-alpha07"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.0-alpha07"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:1.3.0-alpha07"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-alpha07"
```

Update:
I try to save the picture into the **internal** storage with:

```
val file = File(context.filesDir, System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
file.createNewFile()
```

Comment: In the docs, `takePicture()` is not supposed to return any value. Do you mean `onImageSaved` is never called? Do you get anything in `onError` ?
Here is the reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions,java.util.concurrent.Executor,androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback)

Comment: Appears to be related to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238368992?pli=1)

Comment: @Orcun yes sorry that was not clear. I mean that the onImageSaved Callback and not even the onError Callback gets called.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII My naive assumption would be that it is related to some file permission issue. I know in API 29/Android 10 some permission logic changed. I am not able to spot it directly from your code. Maybe you need some "WRITE" permission too? Also, is your target file's location in external storage? Or is it in Media storage? It might change how you should ask the permission.

Comment: @Orcun I updated my question, I use internal storage to store the picture so I am not sure if its really a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

try enabling the `requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the Manifest.

If it works properly after that, then it's the permission issue, not the camera issue. If it doesn't, then let me know.

Add the write storage permission in the Manifest as well, otherwise the manifest tag won't even matter.

Give it a try and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but no change. I forgot to mention that I don't use external storage at all for the target file but use internal storage (Updated my question)

Comment: Also tried with: context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) and your suggestions. Also no change

Comment: Hi @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII. I have tried your code and it's working perfectly for me.
Device :- Samsung A31
Android Version :- 12